# Перелистывание от одного item из array list к другому

Tags: android-studio

Очень сложно объяснить и предчувствую ругательства, извиняюсь заранее.
У меня когда первый array (numbers) список на экране и я нажимаю на первый из списка и на экране появляется первый из второго списка array (letters) 
Мне нужно чтобы когда я нахожусь во втором списке (letters) и делаю движение пальцем по экрану вниз (swipe) у меня меня появлялся следующий по порядку со второго же списка (letters)
Вот код который я написал
Две активити:

1-я:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> numbers;
    ArrayList<String> letters;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_words);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add("1");
        numbers.add("2");
        numbers.add("3");
        numbers.add("4");
        numbers.add("5");
        numbers.add("6");

        letters = new ArrayList<>();
        letters.add("a");
        letters.add("b");
        letters.add("c");
        letters.add("d");
        letters.add("e");
        letters.add("f");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_main, numbers);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String secListItem = letters.get(position);
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("letters", secListItem );
                editor.apply();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

2-я:

```
public class ScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String letters;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        letters = settings.getString("letters", "");

        textView.setText(letters);

    }
}
```

Comment: именно одна буква и должна быть
хотя в идеале нужно чтобы список с цифрами был и когда я кликаю на первый то тот же первый, но отдельно ото всех и должен показаться
и когда я делаю по экрану движение пальцем вниз, то тут и переслистывается на следующий из списка (цифру 2)
тут в коде я упростил чтобы понятней было
можно тупо конечно сделать для каждой буквы отдельный активити, но наверное это не правильно, там просто очень большой array list планируется

Comment: да все правильно

Comment: как то отметить что отвечено?
не знаю как(

Comment: извиняюсь, не сразу нашел, что надо сделать
спасибо еще раз)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать как то так. В первой активити мы выводим список с номерами и определяем позицию, по которой кликнули. Эту позицию передаем в следующюю активити через интент для вывода соответствующей буквы:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> numbers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_words);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add("1");
        numbers.add("2");
        numbers.add("3");
        numbers.add("4");
        numbers.add("5");
        numbers.add("6");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Во второй активити получаем нужную позицию из интента и выводим соответствующюю ей букву. Для того, чтобы их можно было пролистывать, на виджет "вешаем" слушатель жестов, который будет обрабатывать движение, соответственно изменяя букву:

```
public class ScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 50;
    TextView textView;
    LinearLayout container;
    int positionX = 0;
    int positionY;
    List<List<String>> letters;
    GestureDetectorCompat gdt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

        // списки "по вертикали"
        letters = new ArrayList<>();
        // Списки "по горизонтали"
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList b = new ArrayList();


        a.add("A");
        a.add("A1");
        a.add("A2");

        b.add("B");
        b.add("B1");
        b.add("B2");
        b.add("B3");

        letters.add(a);
        letters.add(b);

        // Добавим новый "столбец"
        ArrayList c = new ArrayList();
        // Добавим  элемент в "строку" нового "столбца"
        c.add("C");
        letters.add(c);
        // Добавим новый элемент в "строку" с символом B
        b.add("B4");


        positionY = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);
        gdt = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureListener());
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        updateUI();
        container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
                gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        if (positionY < 0) positionY = 0;
        if (positionY > (letters.size() - 1)) positionY = letters.size() - 1;
        ArrayList<String> x = (ArrayList) letters.get(positionY);
        if (positionX < 0) positionX = 0;
        if (positionX > (x.size() - 1)) positionX = x.size() - 1;
        textView.setText(x.get(positionX));
    }

    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // справа налево
                positionX++;
                updateUI();
                return false;
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // слева направо
                positionX--;
                updateUI();
                return false;
            }

            if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // движение вверх
                positionY++;
                positionX = 0; // в начало строки
                updateUI();
                return false;
            } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // движение вниз
                positionY--;
                positionX = 0; // в начало стоки
                updateUI();
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

`container` - это та область, которая будет реагировать на жест пальцем, в данном случае `LinearLayout`, в котором находится `TextView`/ Эта область реагирования может быть больше самого виджета, в который выводятся буквы.

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает) А если я создам третий Array и при свайпе на странице с letters вправо у меня переходило на третий array по позиции так же как мне это реализовать? Я попробовал это сделать по вашему образцу, но как то не по позиции получается и если я делаю свайп еще раз вправо, то он еще дальше непонятно куда уходит в третьем array, а мне нужно чтобы он останавливался.

Comment: скажем третий array это и цифры и буквы и по порядку будут 1a, 2b и тд.
т.е. мне надо если я открыл A и делаю свайп вправо, то должен открываться 1А, но открывается 2В и если еще свайп вправо сделать, то будет 3С.
И если я с 1А делаю свайп вниз, то по идее должен открываться А, но открывается аж 3
т.е у них есть порядок как раз по очереди

Comment: да B
мне именно нужно добавлять или там можно просто ограниченное количество сделать? тогда в принципе можно
правда не знаю что это такое

Comment: спасибо огромное! все работает)
уже и не надеялся, что получится, но вы сделали это