# кому назначить слушатель swipe события

Tags: android

прет народ!

есть frame layout на нем находятся кнопки, расположенные сеткой, которые занимают практически всю его область, между кнопками есть расстояния. как назначить слушатель swipe  чтоб работал в любой точке фрейма?

[image: фрейм с кнопками] 
может как-то можно задать слушатель определенной части экрана?

Comment: в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/800790/177345) "перелистывание" букв свайпом. GestureDetector вы можете назначить на любые вьюшки, каждой свой

Answer (score 2):

Вставь внутри активити или фрагмента там отлавливаешь движение как то так

```
private View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.i("TAG", "touched down");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.i("TAG", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i("TAG", "touched up");
            break;
    }

    return true;
}};
```